# subtotal not updating after qty change

Tags: reactjs

**Can anybody tell me why subtotal counting after qty change..?**

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-rosalind-hens0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because setting a state is asynchronous in nature -

In you handle change -

```
 const handleChange = evt => {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;
    const newvar = { [name]: value };
    setText({ ...text, ...newvar }); //text state doesn't have updated value so it takes old value

    if (Object.keys(text).length === 0 && text.constructor === Object) {
      setcalcamt(0);
    } else {
    for (var key in text) {
      if (text.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const h = b(Number(key));
        y += h[0].price * text[key];
      }
    }
    console.log("y ", y);
    setcalcamt(y);
    }
  };
```

You need to use useEffect to handle this. Use the code to set calcamt when text changes.

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-snow-qr915?file=/src/components/cart/Cart.js:761-1103)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy..now i understand ;)